# Getting a borderless window to receive mouseMoved events (Cocoa OSX)

Tags: cocoa, macos

I have a little popup window used for selecting images sorted by groups, and I would like to add a selection box around whatever image is being hovered over.  I am trying to this by overriding the mouseMoved event for the window but it seems that a window that has a border-less style mask receives no mouseMoved events even if you have set setAcceptsMouseMoved events to YES.  Is there anyway to make a borderless window receive this events?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to allow the window to become the key window. By default, borderless windows cannot become key. Subclass `NSWindow` and override `-canBecomeKeyWindow`:

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeKeyWindow
{
    return YES;
}
```

Aternatively, you can use an `NSTrackingArea` to do your mouse tracking, which may be easier/better anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot that did the trick.  I don't want to use NSTrackingArea because I need to be able to target OSX versions earlier then 10.5.